# What's the SQLite 3 equivalent syntax of this T-SQL Update command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have opened a database in SQLite browser and attached a backup database with exactly the same schema (but different data).

I now wish to replace the `email` addresses in the first database with the `email` addresses from the backup database where the customer `id`'s match.

In SQL Server, I would write something like this:

```
update tbl_customers
set email = backup.tbl_customers.email
from tbl_customers 
inner join backup.tbl_customers on backup.tbl_customers.id = tbl_customers.id
```

I've seen other SO posts that suggest the following syntax for SQLite which seems like it should work (and these suggestions are marked as the correct answer). But this seems to set all the `email` addresses to the first email address in the corresponding backup database - Clearly not what I want.

```
update tbl_customers
set email = (select backup.tbl_customers.email 
             from backup.tbl_customers 
             where backup.tbl_customers.id = id)
```

The following statement 'works' in SQLite but apparently it overwrites **all** columns in the first database with columns in the corresponding row from the backup database.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tbl_customers 
    SELECT * 
    FROM backup.tbl_customers
```

So how do I update just the `email` address in SQLite?

Comment: `backup.tbl_customers.id = id` is always true because `id` refers to the same table.

Comment: @CL. yes, thanks this would have worked: update tbl_customers
set email = (select bc.email 
                from backup.tbl_customers as bc where bc.id = tbl_customers.id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support `update` with `join`.  But you can do:

```
update tbl_customers
    set email = (select bc.email 
                 from backup.tbl_customers bc
                 where bc.id = tbl_customers.id
                )
    where exists (select 1 
                  from backup.tbl_customers bc
                  where bc.id = tbl_customers.id
                 );
```